# Call shell - only know part of the filename

Tags: vba

My macro creates folders named year.number.description (2016.185.Hello).

The problem is that this name may be changed, so for example, after some days someone renames it to 2016.185.Hi

In the same macro there is an option to open that folder.

I thought that adding ".*" would work but it seems not.

```
Private Sub cmdNumero_Click()

Dim Carpeta As String
Año = Me.txtAny.Value
Numero = Me.txtNumero.Value

Carpeta = "C:\Folder1\Folder2" & "\" & Año & "." & Numero & ".*"

Call Shell("explorer.exe " & Carpeta, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Do you want the user to input the description?

Comment: sorry for late reply LiamH,

No, it's just a button which should open that folder and the user might not know the exact description.

thanks for your time

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a helper function to get you the *actual* folder path.. something like the following:

```
Function GetSubFolderByPartial(sRootPath As String, sSub As String) As String
    Dim oFso As Object
    Dim oTopFolder As Object
    Dim oSubs As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object

    Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oTopFolder = oFso.GetFolder(sRootPath)
    Set oSubs = oTopFolder.SubFolders
    For Each oFolder In oSubs
        If oFolder.Name Like sSub & "*" Then
            GetSubFolderByPartial = oFolder.Path
            Set oFso = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

So, you can simply call it like this:

```
Carpeta = GetSubFolderByPartial("C:\Folder1\Folder2", Año & "." & Numero & ".")
If Len(Carpeta) > 0 Then
    Call Shell("explorer.exe " & Carpeta, vbNormalFocus)
End If
```

Hope that helps